# En React Native como actualizo un FlatList caundo agrego datos al array?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Tengo un FlatList que se crea a partir de un array que comienza con 3 objetos, y tengo un boton que agrega un objeto nuevo con un push al array pero al hacer esto la lista se queda igual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import DATA from './components/DATA';

let contador = 3;

function Item({ title }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const onPressButton = () => {
  contador += 1;
  const id = contador;
  const idstr = id.toString
  const title ='New Item ' + idstr;
  DATA.push({id, title });
};


export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
      <View style={styles.cobro}>
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#CCC" onPress={onPressButton}>
          <Text>Add</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
  cobro: {
    flex: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignContent: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap-reverse',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

La DATA solo es el array que esta guardado en otro documentos:

```
let DATA = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

export default DATA;
```

Básicamente quiero que al apretar el botón se actualice el FlatList con el nuevo item y que cada que lo vuelva a apretar se agreguen los item automáticamente a la lista. Saben alguna forma de lograr esto?.

Les agradesco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te brindo el código corregido con los errores que noté, comenté los detalles importantes para que lo tengas en cuenta

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import DATA from './components/DATA';

function Item({title}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

let contador = 3;

//En este caso el touchable highlight debe contener el estilo "styles.cobro" para que el onPress funcione en toda el area del boton
//El flatlist no se actualiza porque el componente no nota algun cambio en el estado, solo si ocurre un cambio en el estado react renderizara nuevamente el listado
//para ello tienes que indicar DATA como estado usando react hooks, como esta en la linea 27
//en la funcion onPress de Touchable highlight tienes que indicar la función como una funcion flecha, para que solo se ejecute cuando apretes el botón, si no la pones como arrow function se ejecutara apenas se renderize el componente



export default function App() {
  const [dataInState, setDataInState] = useState(DATA); //usando estado mediante react hooks, revisa la documentacion,
  //puede confundirte un poco asi que te recomiendo primero aprendar a usar componentes basados en clase
  //Aqui estas usando un componente basado en funcion con el nombre "App()"
  const onPressButton = () => {
    contador += 1;
    const id = contador;
    const idstr = id.toString(); //Faltaba poner los parentesis en la funcion()
    const title = 'New Item ' + idstr;
    setDataInState([...dataInState, {id, title}]);
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={dataInState}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.cobro}
          underlayColor="#CCC"
          onPress={() => onPressButton()}>
          <Text>Add</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
  cobro: {
    flex: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignContent: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap-reverse',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: Me fue muy útil! Gracias! Una duda, de esta forma los datos si se estan guardando en el array? Es que coloque un log pero me aparece el arreglo vacio, o sabes alguna forma para hacer que los datos se guarden?